# How do I do Debian packaging of a Python package?

Tags: python, debian

I need to write, or find, a script to create a Debian package, using package [`python-support`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-support), from a Python package. The Python package will be pure Python without C extensions.

The Python package for testing purposes will just be a directory with an empty `__init__.py` file and a single Python module, `package_test.py`.

The packaging script *must* use `python-support` to provide the correct bytecode for possible multiple installations of Python on a target platform, i.e. v2.5 and v2.6 on [Ubuntu 9.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaunty#Ubuntu_9.04_(Jaunty_Jackalope)) (Jaunty Jackalope).

Most advice I find while googling are just examples of nasty hacks that don't even use `python-support` or `python-central`.

I have spent hours researching this, and the best I can come up with is to hack around the script from an existing open source project, but I don't know which bits are required for what I'm doing.

Has anyone here made a Debian package out of a Python package in a reasonably non-hacky way?

I'm starting to think that it will take me more than a week to go from no knowledge of Debian packaging and `python-support` to getting a working script. How long has it taken others?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would take the sources of an existing Debian package, and replace the actual package in it with your package. To find a list of packages that depend on python-support, do

```
 apt-cache rdepends python-support
```

Pick a package that is `Architecture: all`, so that it is a pure-Python package. Going through this list, I found that e.g. python-flup might be a good starting point.
To get the source of one such package, do

```
apt-get source <package>
```

To build it, do

```
cd <packagesrc>
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

When editing it, expect that you only need the files in the `debian` folder; replace all references to flup with your own package name.

Once you get started, it should take you a day to complete.

Comment: Note: since this answer was written, `python-support` was deprecated in favor of `dh_python2`. [Transition to dh_python2](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/TransitionToDHPython2) is briefly described on Debian wiki.

Comment: @drdaeman @Martin: dh_python2 is now shipped directly in the `python` package, so this recipe doesn't work so well anymore. How would you update it?

Answer (score 35):

The right way of building a .deb package is using `dpkg-buildpackage`, but sometimes it is a little bit complicated. Instead you can use `dpkg -b <folder>`, and it will create your Debian package.

These are the basics for creating a Debian package with `dpkg -b <folder>` with any binary or with any kind of script that runs automatically without needing manual compilation (Python, Bash, Perl, and Ruby):

1. Create the files and folders in order to recreate the following structure:

   ```
    ProgramName-Version/
    ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN
    ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN/control
    ProgramName-Version/usr/
    ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/
    ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/your_script
   ```

   The scripts placed at `/usr/bin/` are directly called from the terminal. Note that I didn't add an extension to the script. Also you can notice that the structure of the .deb package will be the structure of the program once it's installed. So if you follow this logic, if your program has a single file, you can directly place it under `ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/your_script`, but if you have multiple files, you should place them under `ProgramName-Version/usr/share/ProgramName/all your files` and place only one file under `/usr/bin/` that will call your scripts from `/usr/share/ProgramName/`.
2. Change all the folder permission to root:

   ```
    chown root:root -R /path/to/ProgramName-Version
   ```
3. Change the script's permissions:

   ```
    chmod 0755 /path/to/the/script
   ```
4. Finally, you can run: `dpkg -b /path/to/the/ProgramName-Version` and your .deb package will be created! (You can also add the post/pre install scripts and everything you want. It works like a normal Debian package.)

Here is an example of the `control` file. You only need to copy-paste it in to an empty file called "control" and put it in the `DEBIAN` folder.

```
Package: ProgramName
Version: VERSION
Architecture: all
Maintainer: YOUR NAME <EMAIL>
Depends: python2.7, etc , etc,
Installed-Size: in_kb
Homepage: http://example.com
Description: Here you can put a one line description. This is the short Description.
 Here you put the long description, indented by one space.
```

---

The full article about Debian packages can be read [here](https://github.com/rsm-gh/build-deb/blob/master/DEBIAN_BASICS.md).

Comment: thanks, for the guide. How can I add pre/post inst scripts?

Comment: @Gleb the pre/post scripts must be placed inside the `DEBIAN` folder. Simply add your script with the right name `preinst`, `postinst`, `prerm` [etc..](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html). I'm happy it helped you :)

Comment: It turns out, the mentioned (full) article has gone.. (

Answer (score 22):

I think you want http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb:

> stdeb produces Debian source packages
>   from Python packages via a new
>   distutils command, sdist_dsc.
>   Automatic defaults are provided for
>   the Debian package, but many aspects
>   of the resulting package can be
>   customized (see the customizing
>   section, below). An additional
>   command, bdist_deb, creates a Debian
>   binary package, a .deb file.

Answer (score 20):

Most of the answers posted here are outdated, but fortunately a great Debian wiki post has been made recently, which explains the current best practices and describes how to build Debian packages for Python modules and applications.

- http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging

Comment: The link now redirects to *"[Python/LibraryStyleGuide](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide)"* and the link is probably (effectively) broken. Or alternatively, which part is relevant? Can you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

First off, there are plenty of Python packages already in Debian; you can download the source (including all the packaging) for any of them either using `apt-get source` or by visiting http://packages.debian.org.

You may find the following resources of use:

- [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/)
- [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/)
- [Debian Python Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/)
- [Debian Python Modules Team](http://wiki.debian.org/Teams/PythonModulesTeam)