# Distributing a Python Software for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, python, packaging

I am writing my first software in Python for Ubuntu (or Debian based Linux). I am looking for a good advise on the best way to distribute my software.

The easist alternative that I can think of at the moment is to archive the python code into *.tar.gz, and let user execute the  main python script as an executable to run the software. I realize that this may not be the best approach.

I looked at the Debian maintainer guide: "http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-dother.en.html", not too sound lazy, but the guide looks very intimidating for a beginner. Are there any other tutorial that show how to create a debian package for a beginner ?

If anyone has a suggestion do let me know. Thanks ^_^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debian packaging of a Python package.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/debian-packaging-of-a-python-package)

Answer (score 3):

Just sending them the source in a tarball is perfectly fine. You could also put it up on http://pypi.python.org/pypi. How else were you thinking? There are lots of ways of doing it really. Jut distributing source is probably the easiest.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I quite used to downloading an 'installer' that installs an application to the OS, or using the Ubuntu software center to install an application. ALthough I am very happy to distribute the source and write a simple read me, this approach seem 'unconventional'. But I am pretty happy with it =)

Comment: The cononical way to distribute python app is through distutils or setuptools. That way you can just install it with easy_install. There is some documentation on how to do that in the link I posted.

Answer (score -3):

[Here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html). This is the official, distribution-agnostic way to package and distribute a python program. **Use this one**, you'll have to learn it anyway one day.

Here, instead, is a cheap and dirty hack:

1. Make a directory `/programname/`;
2. Put your whole project folder in a subdirectory `/program/`;
3. Put a file `programname.sh` in your `/programname/` folder;
4. Let this `programname.sh` call your python files.

If you want to go on on the non-standard path, you might:

1. Require that the program is executed as root;
2. Make it create a shell script in `/usr/bin` called programname, which executes `python /path/to/_main_.py`

Comment: -1 for having a bash script start a python program. What's the point of that?

Comment: The point is, working for an unexperienced user - I think that was the point in the question, too. As in: After unpacking the .tar.gz, the user sees a single file (as opposed to the whole source) and a folder; the file is called with the program name (as opposed to _main_.py); in ubuntu after clicking on it you will be asked if you want to execute it (as opposed to opening it in an editor). I thought the asker's concerns went in this direction.

Comment: What? You can't run a non executable file just because it ends in .sh.

Comment: Edited previous comment, did not get you before. Also would like to note that I pointed out the correct distribution method before suggesting the hack - that was just a harmless solution to distribute your program to friends without having to explain them how to use it.

Comment: Ubuntu will try to run main.py if it's executable as well. Just like it will open programname.sh in an editor if it's not executable. And the distributer has absolutely no control over this setting.

Comment: did you notice the rest of my answer/comment? also nope, the default setting for double click on for .py files, even when executable, is the text editor. then again, if the problem is a shell script, then just put another .py file: the thing I wanted him to achieve is, having a user-friendly named file to start the program; non putting the user in a directory with lots of files forcing him to read a manual to know that it should open _main_.py. doesn't look blasphemous to me.