# Making a .deb file from a Python file

Tags: python, package, eps, deb

After following http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=406069 I got to know how to make a .deb file which automatically places the Python file as an executable to `/usr/bin` directory. I want my program to have a structure like that of "grep". Which libraries should I use, and what should be the structure of the programs.

At libraries, do I have to use `Get::Opt` library?

By the "grep structure" I mean the following:

```
program-name func-name -a arg1 --b arg2 should work
man program-name should open the man page
and
program-name should open an in interactive help shell...
```

Comment: This has more to do with perl programming really than any packages. Also, I really recommend to learn packaging properly - make a cpan-compatible (http://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html) or pypi-compatible (http://docs.python.org/distutils/) package. Then create a deb via debuild/pdebuild (http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ and http://joey.kitenet.net/talks/debhelper/debhelper-slides.pdf). It's a lot of work at the beginning, but it will save you loads of trouble a couple of weeks / months from now.

Comment: And what if I have to do the same for python??

Comment: By cpan-compatible I meant a perl package that interacts well with perl environment. Pypi is the similar service for python's packages. If you have the standard `Makefile.pl` in your perl package or a standard `setup.py` in your python package, debhelper will do the "right thing". The `%: dh $@` snippet from "not your grandpa's debhelper" should be all you need for the debian part.

Comment: Regarding the options - perl has `Getopt::Long` (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Getopt-Long/lib/Getopt/Long.pm and others), python has `optparse` (or `argparse` in 2.7+ http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

Comment: The application I am developing is not necessary a python module, it is an api to some part of my project. Anyway I would like into what you have said, and hopefully will get some nice solution + lot of learning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do Debian packaging of a Python package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/how-do-i-do-debian-packaging-of-a-python-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of examples of Debian packaging for Python packages at http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/python-modules/packages. Many of the projects include man page support, such as http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/python-modules/packages/python-paver/trunk/debian/

Comment: The second link seems to be broken now.

Comment: The first link is broken too