# Python: Handling modules

Tags: python, linux, module, installation, debian

I wrote a program which uses a number of built in modules. The program is meant to be used by different persons on their systems. They dont have enough knowledge in python to install it when their system doesnt have the module needed to run the program. Is there any way of handling that.

Also I want to package the program as an executable in linux. It contains 3 py files and one text file only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to create a debian package that handles the dependencies and the installation process.

I'm an Ubuntu user but this [Complete Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) should help you get started. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an executable that contains your python modules and the python interpreter. You can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) for creating such an executable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this on a debian distribution is to [package your python application in a debian package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/debian-packaging-of-a-python-package). You can use [this module to make life easier](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb).