# Is there a standard way to create Debian packages for distributing Python programs?

Tags: python, debian, packaging, distutils, debhelper

There is a ton of information on how to do this, but since *"there is more than one way to skin a cat"*, and all the tutorials/manuals that cover a bit of the process seem to make certain assumptions which are different from other tutorials, I still didn't manage to grasp it.

So far this is what I think I understood.

1. My final goal should be that of creating a "binary" .deb package. Such package will be platform-independent (32/64 bit) as all Python programs are such.
2. To create a "binary" package I need first to create a source package.
3. To create the source package I can use either `CDBS` or `debhelper`. Debhelper is the recommended way for beginners.
4. The core of creating a source package is populating the `DEBIAN` directory in the source directory with a number of files clarifying where files need to be copied, what copyright and licensing scheme they are subject to, what dependencies they have, etc...
5. Step #4 can be largely automated the `dh_make`command *if* the Python source also comes with a distutils' `setup.py` script.

Now my questions:

1. **Is my understanding of the process correct?** Is there anything I am missing, or anything that I got wrong?
2. Step #5 is really the more confusing to me: specifically the two points that remains most obscure to me are:

   - **How do I write a `setup.py` script that install a stand-alone programme?** **EDIT:** By *standalone programme* I mean a program intended to be used by a desktop user (as opposed to a *module* which I understand like a collection of functionality to be used by other software after having been imported). In my specific case I would actually need *two* such "programs": the main software and a separate utility (in effect a second "program" that should be in the same package with the other one).
   - **What are the specificities of such a script for DEB packages?** The official documentation only seems to deal with RPM and Windows stuff...

BTW: These are the best sources of information that I could find myself so far. If you have anything better than this, please share! :)

- [Ubuntu's Python packaging guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python#The_debhelper_way)
- [Creating a .deb package from a python setup.py](http://ghantoos.org/2008/10/19/creating-a-deb-package-from-a-python-setuppy/) (it *shows* the steps, but it doesn't *explain* them enough for me to follow along)
- [ShowMeDo video on "creating a .deb package out of a python
  program"](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=linuxJensMakingDebSeries) (it doesn't seem up-to-date and - if I got it right - will produce packages for personal use, without dependencies
  and without a signed changelog and other key data that will make it incompatible with the Debian policy).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do Debian packaging of a Python package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/how-do-i-do-debian-packaging-of-a-python-package)

Comment: 3 bottom links are broken.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It looks like [stdeb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) will do what you want.

Also, for installing scripts, I strongly recommend [distribute's console_scripts](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) entry point support.

Answer (score 15):

The right way of building a deb package is using `dpkg-buildpackage`, but sometimes it is a little bit complicated. Instead you can use `dpkg -b <folder>`, and it will create your Debian package.

These are the basics for creating a Debian package with `dpkg -b <folder>` with any binary or with any kind of script that runs automatically without needing manual compilation (Python, Bash, Perl, and Ruby):

1. Create the files and folders in order to recreate the following structure:

   ```
    ProgramName-Version/
    ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN
    ProgramName-Version/DEBIAN/control
    ProgramName-Version/usr/
    ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/
    ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/your_script
   ```

   The scripts placed at `/usr/bin/` are directly called from the terminal, note that I didn't add an extension to the script. Also you can notice that the structure of the deb package will be the structure of the program once it's installed. So if you follow this logic if your program has a single file, you can directly place it under `ProgramName-Version/usr/bin/your_script`, but if you have multiple files, you should place them under `ProgramName-Version/usr/share/ProgramName/all your files` and place only one file under `/usr/bin/` that will call your scripts from `/usr/share/ProgramName/`
2. Change all the folder permission to root:

   ```
    chown root:root -R /path/to/ProgramName-Version
   ```
3. Change the script's permissions:

   ```
    chmod 0755 /path/to/the/script
   ```
4. Finally, you can run: `dpkg -b /path/to/the/ProgramName-Version` and your deb package will be created! (You can also add the post/pre inst scripts and everything you want, it works like a normal Debian package)

---

Here is an example of the `control` file. You only need to copy-paste it in to an empty file called "control" and put it in the DEBIAN folder.

```
Package: ProgramName
Version: VERSION
Architecture: all
Maintainer: YOUR NAME <EMAIL>
Depends: python2.7, etc , etc,
Installed-Size: in_kb
Homepage: http://example.com
Description: Here you can put a one line description. This is the short Description.
 Here you put the long description, indented by one space.
```

---

The full article about Debian packages can be read [here](https://github.com/rsm-gh/build-deb/blob/master/DEBIAN_BASICS.md).

Answer (score 10):

[This article by Barry Warsaw](http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/05/from-python-package-to-ubuntu-package.html) helped me in getting quite far through the process. I still had to do a lot of searching on the side, though, and I read most of the [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/) some time in the past.

Having a good `setup.py` is a really good advice. I found these two guides quite good:

- [Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [Distribute documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html)

Comment: The Ubuntu Packaging guide for python is not working anymore.

Answer (score 7):

There are several libraries out there which abstract away all the necessary steps and let you transform your Python package into a Debian package with a single command.

Assuming your python package already has the `setup.py`, in the directory where `setup.py` is located, you could use:

- [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) (Already mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7112197/3937850), install with `pip install stdeb`). To create a Debian package, run:

  ```
  python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
  ```

  The output `.deb` file will be located in the `bdist_deb` directory.
- [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) (install with `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc fpm`). To create a Debian package, run:

  ```
  fpm -s python -t deb setup.py
  ```
- [py2deb](https://github.com/paylogic/py2deb) (install with `pip install py2deb`). To create a Debian package, run:

  ```
  py2deb -r . .
  ```

Each of these libraries has its own caveats, so you might want to try what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

This method works for me.

1. install stdeb.   (pip install stdeb)
2. create setup.py. I'm using PyCharm. This will  (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-setup-py.html)
   write these commands in your project directory.
3. sudo apt-get install python3-stdeb fakeroot python-all
4. python3 setup.py sdist
5. sudo python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
6. your deb file is in the deb_dist directory that is in your project