# How to run a python script in a central environment

Tags: python

I have written a beautiful program (imo) and I would like to implement it into a proper application for others to use.

My program scrapes data from the web, sends it to a MySQL server, and does some simple calculations with it. How can I make it so that the code runs in a central environment (Server or something?) and not just my computer?

Not the entire program has to be run centrally, but at least the data should be stored in a central environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187362/how-to-deploy-python-script)

Comment: you can install python on the central environment (server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not the perfect way of deploying your application. It depends on so many things, but at a minimum this is due to your application type: Is it a Server or client application?

Assuming you want only the data part to be centralized, you probably have a client application which relies on a database server. These are two different requirements, so lets treat that independently:

1. Database server:
   You need to have a database server publicly available on the internet. The bare minimum you need for that is a assigned IPv4 address. It doesn't matter which device runs your database server. It could be your own server, an AWS application or even a rasperry pi. That's completely up to you and depends on factors like availabilty, computing resources, required storage, etc.
2. Client application:
   The client application likely runs on a user's machine. You should ask yourself first which operating systems you want to support. Python is mostly OS-independent, but that is not granted for every single use case or instruction. If you want to reach the most users you should go for a windows-based OS. Then you should probably look for [building an exe file from python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734926/build-a-exe-for-windows-from-a-python-3-script). If you want to support linux you probably want to [build a deb-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110604/is-there-a-standard-way-to-create-debian-packages-for-distributing-python-progra).

As you see, you should clarify first, *what exactly* you want to archive and then break it down into smaller packets.