# Debian package dependencies in setup.py or nice setup way?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, apt, deb

I have written a Python program to receive values from a Bluetooth device. For this I built a wrapper around the `gatttool`. Now I want to build this as a Debian package for this I use `setup.py`.

This my `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    name="b35t",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="Tool to connect to B35T+.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author="Sebastian",
    author_email="hackwiki2.0@gmail.com",
    license="MIT License",
    packages=['b35t'],
    package_dir={'b35t': 'b35t/'},
    install_requires=[
        'pexpect',
        'ptyprocess'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Environment :: Console",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux"
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'b35t = b35t.b35t:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

And I use this command to build the Debain package.
`python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb`

Unfortunately I need `bluez` as a dependency. As far as I know install_requires are PyPI package and not Debian packages

How is it possible to define Debian dependencys? And do this in a clean way? (And not with building the packages and then customizing them.)

If anyone wants to see the code, here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/53845714nF/OWON_B35T).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7110604/15751564

Comment: In some more detail, run `stdeb3` with `-depends`; see https://pypi.org/project/stdeb3/#customizing-the-produced-debian-source-package-config-options

Comment: I use `sudo python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb3.command bdist_deb` but i get this Error: `error: invalid command 'bdist_deb'`.