# Creating an installer for a python GTK3 application

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, cross-platform, gtk3

I have just finished developing a Python 2.7 application using Gtk3 for GUI.
My question is, how can I now create an installer for Windows, Mac, and Linux (possibly three different installers) for my end-users to easily download the application without having to download python and GTK and such.

I have never created an installer from a python script before. I have heard that are some tools for this purpose (py2exe? pyinstaller?), but I wouldn't know how and what to pack with them in order for it to be able to use Gtk3.

Comment: If you want to do an installer for Linux you will find that there are different kind of packages.. ( for ach linux, for debian based... etc).. If by linux you mean GNU-Linux Ubuntu or Debian, Mint etc i recommend you my answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382569/how-do-i-do-debian-packaging-of-a-python-package/25275227#25275227) thread. It will only take you some minutes.

Comment: Use a [Debian Package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25275227/3672754) for GNU-Linux. But be aware that this is only for Debian/Ubuntu based distributions! There are more kind of distributions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a few days of searching the internet for a solution, I have finally stumbled upon [this blog-post](http://gmigdos.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/how-to-bundle-python-gtk3-apps-on-windows-with-py2exe/), that helped me to create an .exe to run the program on Windows, which was my main goal.

For future reference, these were the steps I took:

- Make sure you have Python installed, with GTK+3 ([install from here](http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php)) and PyGObject ([install from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar)) installed. **IMPORTANT**: When installing PyGObject, make sure you select both Gtk+ **AND** Gstreamer (for some reason you must have it for py2exe to get all the dlls)
- At the same directory as your project, create a new python file containing the following script. Make sure that you change 'main.py' to the name of your own main script file (the one that launches your App):

---

*setup.py*:

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 
import sys, os, site, shutil

site_dir = site.getsitepackages()[1] 
include_dll_path = os.path.join(site_dir, "gnome") 

gtk_dirs_to_include = ['etc', 'lib\\gtk-3.0', 'lib\\girepository-1.0', 'lib\\gio', 'lib\\gdk-pixbuf-2.0', 'share\\glib-2.0', 'share\\fonts', 'share\\icons', 'share\\themes\\Default', 'share\\themes\\HighContrast'] 

gtk_dlls = [] 
tmp_dlls = [] 
cdir = os.getcwd() 
for dll in os.listdir(include_dll_path): 
    if dll.lower().endswith('.dll'): 
        gtk_dlls.append(os.path.join(include_dll_path, dll)) 
        tmp_dlls.append(os.path.join(cdir, dll)) 

for dll in gtk_dlls: 
    shutil.copy(dll, cdir) 

# -- change main.py if needed -- #
setup(windows=['main.py'], options={ 
    'py2exe': { 
        'includes' : ['gi'], 
        'packages': ['gi'] 
    } 
}) 

dest_dir = os.path.join(cdir, 'dist') 

if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    os.makedirs(dest_dir)

for dll in tmp_dlls: 
    shutil.copy(dll, dest_dir) 
    os.remove(dll) 

for d  in gtk_dirs_to_include: 
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(site_dir, "gnome", d), os.path.join(dest_dir, d))
```

---

- Run setup.py, preferably from command line by typing **python setup.py py2exe**, and it will create two new directories in your project's folder: **\build** and **\dist**. The **\dist** folder is the one we care about, in which you will find all the essential Dlls, and your program's newly created .exe, named after your main python script (main.exe in my case).
- **Important Additional Note:** if you are using any non-python file in your project (css file in my case) be sure to copy and paste it to the **\dist** directory, or the app won't be able to find it!

---

As far as I'm aware of this solution only work for distributing for Windows (which was my main goal), but in the future I am going to try and do the same for Linux and OSX, and I'll update the answer accordingly